# After Insert MySQL Trigger to update values or insert a new row in another table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables,

```
RawFeed , SellerList.
```

When a new row is inserted in `RawFeed`, I need to insert a row in `SellerList` if a corresponding `SellerID` does not exist in `SellerList`,

Otherwise, I need to increment two column values in the `SellerList` table for that `SellerID`.

Here is my Trigger code-

```
CREATE TRIGGER `SellerListUpdate` AFTER INSERT ON `RawFeed`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        --CHECK SELLER ID EXISTS OR NOT.
        DECLARE SELLEREXISTS INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO SELLEREXISTS FROM SellerList WHERE SellerList.SellerID=NEW.seller_id;

        IF SELLEREXISTS=0 THEN
            --INSERT ROW
            INSERT INTO SellerList(`SellerID`, `Total`, `Active`) VALUES(NEW.seller_id, 1, 1);
        ELSE
            --UPDATE ROW
            UPDATE SellerList SET Total=Total+1, Active=Active+1 WHERE SellerList.SellerID=NEW.seller_id;
        END IF;
    END
```

And I am receiving this error-

```
SQL Error(1064): You have an error in your SQL Syntax;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the delimiter

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER `SellerListUpdate` AFTER INSERT ON `RawFeed`
FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        --CHECK SELLER ID EXISTS OR NOT.
        DECLARE SELLEREXISTS INT;
        SELECT COUNT(*) INTO SELLEREXISTS FROM SellerList WHERE SellerList.SellerID=NEW.seller_id;

        IF SELLEREXISTS=0 THEN
            --INSERT ROW
            INSERT INTO SellerList(`SellerID`, `Total`, `Active`) VALUES(NEW.seller_id, 1, 1);
        ELSE
            --UPDATE ROW
            UPDATE SellerList SET Total=Total+1, Active=Active+1 WHERE SellerList.SellerID=NEW.seller_id;
        END IF;
    END
$$
DELIMITER ;
```